# I've read the documentation but my STATIC folder is still not being served

Tags: django

My settings.py file has the static URL set:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The staticfiles app is installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Journal',
    'adminsortable2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I've created a folder inside my app called static/journal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1eGw.png

My template loads static and uses the URL as per documentation:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel='icon' href='{% static "journal/favicon.ico" %}' type='image/x-icon'>
```

And yet when I browse to http://localhost/static/journal/favicon.ico I get an error 404!!!

The rest of my app is accessible at http://localhost (runserver is on port 80 and localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 via hosts file_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add static file urls to url `urls.py`.

In your urls.py:

At the top of the file put these lines:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

At the bottom of the file put these lines:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      view=cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)(serve))
```

Answer (score 0):

from above your question it seems that you are not using the Port number in the url . Can you try http://localhost:80/static/journal/favicon.ico .